# Rx: Buffer with variable back pressured buffer time

Tags: rxjs, system.reactive

I have played a little with Rx, but still consider myself newish to the world. I have a problem, and I am wondering if I can solve it via Rx. My initial use case is in C#, but may later want the same in JS (though if any code snippets in answers, any language of pseudo code is fine)

Currently I have a client app which simply buffers data (transactions) it creates, and sends to the server every 5 seconds. This data can contain many individual transactions, e.g. it has stored many and now come online so we want to send perhaps thousands to the server. When sending many as just described, the 8 second delay and buffering is fine (the data is already delayed anyway). However, when this client is, for example connected, and we create a transaction in real-time (i.e. just 1 or 2 single transactions), I would like to be able to send these immediately, i.e. not wait the 8 seconds.

So it looks similar to the [Rx buffer](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html), crossed with maybe the [debounce](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html)? I have attempted to draw a marble diagram to help explain using an advanced graphic package (not) paint.

[image]

So, to walk through this, the 1st **red** marble is received and forwarded straight away. Next the **yellow** marble is also forwarded straight away as it has been 1 second since the last red marble.

Now the **light blue** marble, and a bunch of others come in less than 1 second, so we now want to buffer these, as we don't want to spam the network with possibly thousands of requests - what we will do here is buffer for say 5  seconds, and then send however many we have buffered, every 5 seconds, until this "spurt" has finished. After this, we then want to return to sending any other "individual" requests as they come.

It doesn't have t be exactly like the above, basically we want

- individual transactions (to user input with a connected client app), to be sent immediately, (or some very small delay)
- Detect when we start getting many transactions, and have this start to 
  "throttle" and then send the buffered batches at some longer time interval apart (eg 5 or 8 seconds)
- Do NOT want to throw away any transactions (marbles), I want to send them all

I have found a number of other posts similar, but not the same as this.

I've come up with some clunky "manual" ways of doing this (using just standard lists, and various timers etc), but was wondering would this be possible using **Rx** to do some of this work, and hopefully less prone to bugs?

Thanks in advance for any help here!

Answer (score 1):

I think you picked it already, `buffer` and `debounce` as the buffer trigger,

> when this client is, for example connected

If you want to added a connection event, you could merge that into `bufferTrigger` as well.

```js
console.clear()

const source = new Rx.Subject();
const bufferTrigger = source.debounceTime(500);

source
  .buffer(bufferTrigger)
  .subscribe(console.log);

setTimeout(() => source.next('red'), 0);
setTimeout(() => source.next('yellow'), 1000);
setTimeout(() => source.next('lightblue'), 3000);
setTimeout(() => source.next('green'), 3100);
setTimeout(() => source.next('blue'), 3200);
setTimeout(() => source.next('pink'), 4000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```

### Example with additional trigger 5 secs after last emit

```js
const source = new Rx.Subject();
const lastEmit = new Rx.Subject();
const maxDelayAfterLastEmit = lastEmit.delay(5000);
const bufferTrigger = source.debounceTime(500)
  .merge(maxDelayAfterLastEmit);

const emits = source
  .buffer(bufferTrigger)
  .do(x => lastEmit.next(x))
  .filter(x => x.length);

var start = new Date().getTime();
emits.subscribe(x => console.log((new Date().getTime() - start)/1000  + "s " + x));

setTimeout(() => source.next('red'), 0);
setTimeout(() => source.next('yellow'), 1000);
setTimeout(() => source.next('lightblue'), 3000);
setTimeout(() => source.next('green'), 3100);
setTimeout(() => source.next('blue1'), 3200);
setTimeout(() => source.next('blue2'), 3300);
setTimeout(() => source.next('blue3'), 3600);
setTimeout(() => source.next('pink1'), 4000);
setTimeout(() => source.next('pink2'), 4400);
setTimeout(() => source.next('pink3'), 4800);
setTimeout(() => source.next('pink4'), 5200);
setTimeout(() => source.next('pink5'), 5600);
setTimeout(() => source.next('pink6'), 6000);
setTimeout(() => source.next('pink7'), 6400);
setTimeout(() => source.next('pink8'), 6800);
setTimeout(() => source.next('pink9'), 7200);
setTimeout(() => source.next('pink10'), 7700);
setTimeout(() => source.next('pink11'), 8200);
setTimeout(() => source.next('pink12'), 8600);
setTimeout(() => source.next('pink13'), 9000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the above answer. This is close, but the only other thing I did want to do was to "force emit" after a certain period if we still had incoming. I have copied and added to your example in this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/9tvjzHrPpGXBNSC4iKuq), (use the browser dev tools to see console output) and if you look at the last batch, they are not emitted until 9 seconds, but I wold like to emit what we have so far at say 5 seconds, and then the rest at 5 second intervals, until done, where we can start the whole pattern over again.

Comment: Aha, I thought it was too easy :). Essentially, you can add extra events to the bufferTrigger with the merge operator, `const bufferTrigger = source.debounceTime(500).merge(someOtherObservable)`. So, is that 5 seconds after the last emit? (e.g 5 seconds after yellow?)

Comment: I've appended my take on the additional criteria. If not quite right, let me know and I'll pick it up again tomorrow.

Comment: So, initially we have the 2 "slow" bits of data added which we want to emit straight away. But once we get to the *lightblue*, all the rest are coming in quickly, so the idea was to batch these, and send whatever we have every say 5 seconds. eg we may have *5.525s* lightblue,green,blue1,blue2,blue3,pink1,pink2,pink3,pink4, and then 5 seconds later another batch, for example *10.525s* pink5,pink6,pink7, pink8,pink9,pink10,pink11,pink12,pink13. If we keep getting data to send added quickly, say < 1 s (eg wa loop going thru records in a db, we batch and send every 5 seconds.

Comment: Once the above is finished (eg all records from the database of data stored while offline are gone), we may then have no more data added to then emit. Eg say after the last pink13, then pink14 is not added until more than say 1 second after pink13. So, since we have had this break, we can then go back to emitting pink14 immediately. So we just want to batch longer when we have lots of data being added quickly, and then when this stops, go back to sending "individual" bits of data immediately. I probably didn't quite get my marble diagram to reflect quite what I meant.

Comment: The problem with what is appended to the answer, is we correctly get the red and yellow emitted as soon as they arrive, we then get a few batched ans sent around 4 seconds later, and then the next batch only 1 seconds later (each of these we wanted 5 seconds apart, so there would then be more "marbles" in each batch as it has "waited" longer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If I can 'boil it down' to some simple rules, I'll translate them into Rx and post a revision.

Comment: Did you end up solving this aspect?

Comment: @AdrianBaker - no I didn't, but would, still be interested (my whole last year saw me get interrupted from this). It is still something I want to revisit (now that I have been reminded of it)